# How to unit test if an action has been dispatched in another action?

Tags: angular, rxjs, jestjs, ngxs

I'd like, as the title says, to test that my action dispatches another action when the observable returns.

Here is my code :

```
@Action(FetchRoles)
fetchRoles(ctx: StateContext<RoleStateModel>, action: FetchRoles) {
  return this.rolesGateway.fetchRoles()
    .pipe(
      tap(roles => ctx.patchState({ roles })),
    );
}

@Action(UpdateMyRole)
updateMyRole(ctx: StateContext<RoleStateModel>, action: UpdateMyRole) {
  return this.rolesGateway.updateMyRole(action.roleToUpdate)
    .pipe(
      tap(() => {
        ctx.dispatch(new FetchRoles()); // <-- WHAT I WANT TO SPY AND TEST
        this.feedbackManagerService.success('Role updated');
      }),
    );
}
```

I've tried to test it synchronously, like this

```
store.dispatch(new UpdateApplicationRole(applicationCode, roleManage));

expect(gateway.updateMyRole).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(gateway.updateMyRole).toHaveBeenCalledWith(roleToUpdate);
expect(gateway.fetchRoles).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(gateway.fetchRoles).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
expect(feedbackManagerService.success).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(feedbackManagerService.success).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Role updated');
```

But also with `fakeAsync ... tick(100)`

```
store.dispatch(new UpdateApplicationRole(applicationCode, roleManage));
tick(100)
...
```

Or even an `async ... await`

```
await store.dispatch(new UpdateApplicationRole(applicationCode, roleManage));
...
```

But everytime, I receive only calls in the `gateway.updateMyRole`, not the 4 after.
Initially, I wanted to test only the `ctx.dispatch(new FetchRoles())`

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was overthinking. I just needed to mock my gateway observables with a value :
`of()` => `of(null)`